# Pagination for custom module in joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, module, pagination, joomla2.5

We have already created custom module for searching but pagination not working. we have used following code for pagination.

```
    jimport( 'joomla.html.pagination' );
    $pagNav = new JPagination(6, 0, 5);

    $pageNav = new JPagination( $db->loadResult(), $lim0, $lim );

    echo $pagNav->getListFooter();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jimport( 'joomla.html.pagination' );

$pageNav = new JPagination( $db->loadResult(), $lim0, $lim );

echo $pageNav->getListFooter();
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of your `pagNav` variable was, but it sure looked out of place. This is also assuming you're setting `$lim0` and `$lim` correctly, of course.

Comment: I use your code and I'm setting up `$lim0` and `$lim` correctly but I'm getting error 404 page not found when I click on some of the pagination buttons (only first page works).